# How do I use a boost condition variable to wait for a thread to complete processing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using a conditional variable to stop a thread until another thread has completed processing it's task queue (long story). So, on one thread I lock and wait:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
m_condition.wait(lock);
```

Once the other thread has completed it's tasks, it signals the waiting thread as follows:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_parent.m_mutex);
m_parent.m_condition.notify_one();
```

The problem I am seeing is that the waiting thread does not stop waiting unless I set a breakpoint on the instructions following it (I am using xcode, fyi). Yes, this seems strange. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Am I mis-using the condition variable?

Comment: The code is a bit confusing ... is the first `m_mutex` the same instance as the second `m_parent.m_mutex`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you are misusing the condition variable.  "Condition variables" are really just the signaling mechanism.  You also need to be testing a condition.  In your case what might be happening is that the thread that is calling `notify_one()` actually completes before the thread that calls `wait()` even starts.  (Or at least, the `notify_one()` call is happening before the `wait()` call.)  This is called a "missed wakeup."

The solution is to actually have a variable which contains the condition you care about:

```
bool worker_is_done=false;

boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
while (!worker_is_done) m_condition.wait(lock);
```

and

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);
worker_is_done = true;
m_condition.notify_one();
```

If `worker_is_done==true` before the other thread even starts waiting then you'll just fall right through the while loop without ever calling `wait()`.

This pattern is so common that I'd almost go so far as to say that if you don't have a `while` loop wrapping your `condition_variable.wait()` then you always have a bug.  In fact, when C++11 adopted something similar to the boost::condtion_variable they added a new kind of wait() that takes a predicate lambda expression (essentially it does the `while` loop for you):

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
bool worker_is_done=false;


std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
cv.wait(lk, []{return worker_is_done;});
```

Comment: What is  `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex);`  in the waiting thread needed for? notify_one() does not take args.

Comment: It is there to provide an atomic write to `worker_is_done`. The alternative is to declare the type as `atomic<bool>` instead of just `bool`.

Comment: @DavidStone What if we are running the code on a processor in which 1 byte assignment is atomic eg. x86? We won't need the lock in that case, is it?

Comment: @user3286661: No, your processor is irrelevant. If you have two possibly overlapping accesses to a variable, at least one of which is a write, then your program's behavior is undefined unless the variable is a mutex or an atomic, basically. Your hardware may be 'safe', but your compiler can do whatever optimizations it wants under the assumption that you are not doing anything undefined. For instance, maybe it will combine multiple variables into one because you cannot tell the difference (unless you have undefined behavior).

Comment: @DavidStone Could you please write an answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632294/using-a-lock-with-condition-variables)? I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented an example that illustrates how to use boost condition, based in the discussion.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex io_mutex;
bool worker_is_done = false;
boost::condition_variable condition;

void workFunction()
{
    std::cout << "Waiting a little..." << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    worker_is_done = true;
    std::cout << "Notifying condition..." << std::endl;
    condition.notify_one();
    std::cout << "Waiting a little more..." << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(io_mutex);
    boost::thread workThread(&workFunction);

    while (!worker_is_done) condition.wait(lock);
    std::cout << "Condition notified." << std::endl;
    workThread.join();
    std::cout << "Thread finished." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Boost condition variable example](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qHyMlvEF1IEuOY_dN-O74lkvtxrXRC6HJ3eQvXd_Fl8/pub)

Comment: Shouldn't you take the lock in workFunction before setting worker_is_done to true?